# C# Switch results to list then to comma separated values

Tags: c#

How would I make a switch statement populate a list, or comma delimited string?

For example

```
switch(test)
{
   case 0:
      "test"
      break;
   case 1:
      "test2"
      break;
   case 2:
      "test3"
      break;
}
```

So my program will go into this statement multiple times. So lets say it goes in there twice and has case 2 and case 1. I woulld like a string value containing the following:
string value = "test3, test2"

Comment: If you want to pass at the same place multiple times your problem is clearly calling for some kind of loop statement. Anyway you have to be more concise in your problem since it is impossible to interpret it the way that you explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a `List<string>` would be ideal to hold your values, you can create a comma separated string from that using `string.Join()`:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
//add items
myList.Add("test2");

//create string from current entries in the list
string myString = string.Join("," myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

By multiple times, you mean a loop? You can just have a string and concatenate the string using + operator, or you can just have a list and add to it everytime the case condition is satisfied.

But if you mean by conditional flow so that you want case 0, 1 and 2 to all be evaluated, then you can simply omit the break and do the same concatenation like I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop and a `StringBuilder`.  If you're doing repeated concatenation, `StringBuilder`s are significantly more efficient than naive `string` concatenation with `+`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(...)
{
    switch(test)
    {
        case 0:
        sb.Append("test");
        break;

        case1:
        sb.Append("test2");
        break;

        case 2:
        sb.Append("test3");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private string strValue = string.Empty;
 private string StrValue
 {
     get
     {
          return strValue ;
     }
     set
     {
          StrValue= string.Concat(strValue , ",", value);
     }
 }

switch(test)
{
case 0:
StrValue = "test"
break;

case1:
StrValue = "test2"
break;

case 2:
StrValue = "test3"
breakl
}
```

Where ever you used StrValue remove "," if "," comes in the last.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways you can do it, a very simple one is:

```
string csv = "";

while (yourCriteria) {
  string value;

  // insert code to get your test value

  switch(test)
  {
    case 0:
      value = "test";
      break;
    case1:
      value = "test2";
      break;
    case 2:
      value = "test3";
      break;
  }

  csv += value + ", ";
}

csv = csv.Length > 0 ? csv.Substring(0, csv.Length-2) : "";
```